# If column A is equal to current month then do. I am needing my formula updated please

Tags: google-sheets, split, count, vlookup, google-query-language

I have a formula to count number of times the word "test" is on a certain sheet

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER('Archived D'!E:E,ISNUMBER(MATCH('Archived D'!H:H,Match!$A$2:$A$12,0))),A2) + COUNTIF('IAD'!E:E, A:A)
```

I need the formula to only count total of "test" when column "A" in "IAD" is equal to the current month. I tried

```
+ COUNTIFS('IAD'!E:E, A:A, 'IAD'!A:A, MONTH(TODAY()))
```

That is giving me zero for my count and that isn't right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY({Archive!A3:H; IAD!A:H}, 
 "select Col3,count(Col3) 
  where month(Col1)+1 = "&MONTH(TODAY())&" 
    and Col8 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Names!A2:A)&"' 
  group by Col3"), 2, 0), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Given answer was ultimately correct